# How to add a timestamp to all res.json() express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have a bunch of routers that send a JSON response. I don't want to add a

```
{...,"timestamp": new Date()}
```

to every single response. Along with other properties like the baseurl and etc

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @wlh - Middleware could add custom headers, but I think the OP is looking to modify the object that is being sent with `res.json(obj)` to add properties to it before sending.  Can't do that with middleware because the object isn't yet known.

Comment: @jfriend00 Why not? You could have middleware that essentially buffers the response, and will add that field before passing it along to the output stream

Comment: @josh.trow - You mean intercepts data that is later sent on the stream?  Part of the problem is that it's already been turned to JSON at that point.  Plus, there's just no need to do it that way.  Much better to just use a common function that adds the properties before `res.json()` is even called.  Perhaps you could hack it with middleware by intercepting various things, but that does not seem like a clean solution to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree, not the cleanest - better to add a new response method - but if you really don't want to change any existing downstream code, it should be quite doable to override the `res.json` method

Answer (score 2):

Just as in any normal coding, if you want do apply a common operation to a bunch of methods, then create a shared function and call that function from all those methods instead of `res.json(...)`.

```
function sendJsonExtra(res, obj) {
    obj.timestamp = Date.now();
    obj.baseurl = ...
    res.json(obj);    
}
```

Then, just use this function in place of `res.json()` anywhere you want this set of common properties added to your object.

You could also have middleware that would add this function as a method to the `res` object so you could then just call `res.sendJsonExtra(obj)` if you like that structure better.

```
// middleware to add `res.sendJsonExtra()` method to each request
// so other code can then call it as needed
function jsonExtra(req, res, next) {
    res.sendJsonExtra = function(obj) {
        obj.timestamp = Date.now();
        obj.baseurl = ...
        res.json(obj);    
    }
    next();
}

router.use(jsonExtra);
```

Then, any route handlers that want the extra data added, can just call `res.sendJsonExtra(obj)`.  This lets each route handler decide if it wants the extra properties added or not and it makes the code more self documenting vs. monkey patching `res.json()` to change its behavior.

Comment: how can we do this in typescript?

Comment: @asimmehmood - The first part of this answer, defining a function `sendJsonExtra()` that you can call from anywhere can be done in TypeScript just fine by adding the appropriate type information to the function declaration.  Adding new methods to `res` can be accomplished in TypeScript (probably by subclassing where you can define new methods), but that's beyond my TypeScript abilities.

Answer (score -1):

Admittedly it's been a while since I worked in NodeJS, so take this with a grain of salt - but perhaps something like this would work. It should allow for no change of anything downstream - it's not perfect as it does mess with the response object but that's a tradeoff you need to evaluate for yourself.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res._json = res.json;
  res.json = function(obj) {
    // add your fields to obj
    obj.timestamp = new Date();
    // ...
    res._json(obj);
  }
  next();
})

app.use(/* your processing code */);
```

Comment: This monkey patch approach may impact other routes that don't wish to inherit the new functionality.   Plus, it makes reading the code that is calling `res.json()` misleading because it's doing more than just sending the JSON.

Comment: @jfriend00 100% agree - but it does to the best of my understanding answer the requested question with minimal changes to existing code

Comment: Yeah, but, not the most recommended way of solving the problem IMO.